# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'

Tags: discord.py

Не видит библиотеку discord_components.

Не распознает ее в VS code
[image: вфвфв]

Библиотека установлена но почему-то не распознает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема пофиксилась простым выбором места питона в VS code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Перезагрузка всё решила. Делай её после установки пакетов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я немного не понял что нужно сделать, если не сложно, можно по подробнее.

Comment: Закрой и открой VS Code. Если не сработает, будем думать дальше

Comment: А, так не работает.

Comment: Очень странно, попробуй сохранить файл и опять перезапустить VS Code. Пробовал переустанавливать discord-components? Раза 4 проверил, должно работать

Comment: Все равно, не работает.